# not outputting result data with newlines for each json array

Tags: python

The following piece of code is not adding a newline for each data result:

```
if 'result' in data:
    filename = str(data['filename']);
    for imsg in data['result']['data']:
        msg += imsg + '\n'
    with open(filename,"w") as output:
        output.write(msg)
```

I'm trying to overwrite the file with the new data. That's why I used `'w'`.

Hope the information provided is sufficient.

JSON:

```
{
    "format": "json",
    "result": {
        "data": [
            "New Message 1",
            "New Message 2"
        ]
    },
    "total": 2,
    "filename": "\/log.txt"
}
```

Comment: What platform are you on? What application are you using to view the text file?

Comment: on my pc using virtual box, text editor - notepad

Comment: Is it possible to view the newline characters in notepad? I'm thinking that the editor only recognizes `\r\n` as a newline.

Comment: You can replace 4th and 5th line with simple `msg = '\r\n'.join(data['result']['data'])`. `\r\n` is newline notation for windows but it's also accepted by other operating systems.

Comment: In which case you could instead do `import os; msg += imsg + os.linesep`

Comment: yes it should do, i've done it before on php

Comment: Is `msg` a string? Your code snippet doesn't show its definition.

Comment: @Granitosaurus great suggestion except that `'\n'.join(data['result']['data'])` will do because a file opened in `"w"` mode will convert to `\r\n` on write if this is a windows machine.

Comment: That code is adding a newline. The problem must be elsewhere. Can you write a runnable sample that demonstrates the problem? We don't know what's in your data or files and so cannot reproduce it ourselves. For instance, you could create a list that has the first few items from `data['result']['data']` and post that instead. Remember - if we can run it we can help you more!

Comment: @tdelaney please check my question, i've added the json data

Comment: That isn't a valid filename, at least for linux. Are you sure the file is being opened and written or is there an error being raised?

Comment: @tdelaney it is saving fine, just not with new lines

Comment: Cannot reproduce. If I change the filename to `log.txt` and initialize `msg = ''` I get the expected new lines in the file. What mechanism do you use to check for newlines?